# Is the limit to infinity of one over an expression whose limit is infinity zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

Put more correctly, do the following rules regarding limits always hold?

$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{f(x)} = 0 $ where $ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty $

$ \lim\limits_{x \to - \infty} \dfrac{1}{g(x)} = 0 $ where $ \lim\limits_{x \to - \infty} g(x) = \infty $

Comment: Yes, those limits always hold.

Comment: Just try to answer this question: what is the answer when 1 is divided by a very large number such as $\infty$?

Comment: @NandeeshBhatrai: "a very large number such as $\infty$"? Infinity is not a number! (Not in this context, anyway.) Zedfrigg, please ignore Nandeesh's comment.

Comment: @TonyK         infinity is not a number but if you try to define infinity then you can come to the conclusion that **infinity is *infinitely* large**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Yes. They essentially follow from the fact that
if $f(x)>M>0$, then
$$
0<\frac{1}{f(x)}<\frac{1}{M}
$$

Comment: This makes sense, but it's still not clear to me how the rules are provably true. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Zedfrigg: Do you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits?

Comment: Ah, does it rely on that? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Zedfrigg: Yes. That's what you need when you deal with limits seriously.

Comment: Alright, in that case I'll just mark this as the answer now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Zedfrigg: you are welcome!